# SASL error in postgres connection with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql, connection

I am having the following error when trying to make a connection to my database:

```
Conexão estbabelecida com sucesso
Acessar http://localhost:3000
Servidor executando na porta 3000
C:\Users\lopes\Desktop\Javascript\novo-projeto\ExpressEWebpack\node_modules\pg\lib\sasl.js:24
    throw new Error('SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password must be a string')
    ^

Error: SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password must be a string
    at Object.continueSession (C:\Users\lopes\Desktop\Javascript\novo-projeto\ExpressEWebpack\node_modules\pg\lib\sasl.js:24:11)
    at Client._handleAuthSASLContinue (C:\Users\lopes\Desktop\Javascript\novo-projeto\ExpressEWebpack\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:257:10)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at C:\Users\lopes\Desktop\Javascript\novo-projeto\ExpressEWebpack\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:114:12
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\lopes\Desktop\Javascript\novo-projeto\ExpressEWebpack\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:40:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lopes\Desktop\Javascript\novo-projeto\ExpressEWebpack\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Heres my code to connection

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const app = express(); 
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_URL);

try {
    sequelize.authenticate();
    console.log('Conexão estbabelecida com sucesso')
}catch{
    console.log('Erro ao estabelecer conexão');
}

const session = require('express-session');
const flash = require('connect-flash');

const routes = require('./routes')
const path = require('path');


app.use(express.urlencoded({  extended:true }));

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')));

const sessionOptions = session({
    secret:process.env.cookie_secret,
    store: new (require('connect-pg-simple')(session))(),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7}
});

app.use(sessionOptions);
app.use(flash());

app.set('views', path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(routes);

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Acessar http://localhost:3000');
    console.log('Servidor executando na porta 3000');
});
```

I having this error but my dabatase doenst have a password at all, the fact that i dont have a password could interfere in the connection? In some way,password receives null for having no value? I tried to resolve,seeing what's on sasl.js,but it didn't help much

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your **pg_hba.conf** file (on Windows the directory is *\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\data*) change *IPv4* and *IPv6* local connections' method to **trust**. The **scram-sha-256** encryption mechanism expects a password which is why it fails.

Comment: Using the `trust` authentication is at best a temporary solution and if you really trust the incoming connection requests. Why does this error message crop up in the first place? Is this due to wrong password or a password not supplied? What if I want to go back to using the SCRAM-SHA-256 authentication?

Comment: IIRC the database itself does not have a password set-up which may be the reason why the encryption fails. @AnantaKRoy

Comment: For a new installation of Postgres 13 this issue of authentication failure is coming up for me. I do not know for sure if there is something else which needs to be setup for the scram-sha to work out of the box. I had been using Postgres 12 with md5 without any issues.

Comment: You could try to set a password for the database and use the encryption mechanism to see whether it works.

Comment: how to add trust can you show any examples @Rakozay